# "“photos.db” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access while Integrating python osxphotos lib

Tags: python, mobile-automation, ios, mac

Problem :

- **Background** : I am trying to access internal storage and photos using python from iOS real device or simulators & occur failure in a process because you don’t have permission to access
- **Failure reason**  : "“photos.db” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Working Solution** :

  1. Check installed version of "osxphotos"
  2. If not then use ***`pip install osxphotos`*** to install latest version
  3. Create virtual environment locally `python3 -m venv test-virtual-env`
  4. What I missed was the activation (can be done using source test-virtual-env/bin/activate)and access permission for Photos app